# How to vertically align Text inside Container

Tags: flutter

I have a `Wrap` layout with some `Container` children. Each container has a child, `Text`

The `Container` has a fixed height but a flexible width.

How can I vertically align the `Text` inside the `Container`? I tried to use `alignment: Alignment.centerLeft`, but then the Container's width spans the whole parent.

I can not set the width of the `Container` since I don't know what width the text will be.

```
Wrap(
      spacing: 3.0, // gap between adjacent chips
      runSpacing: 3.0, // gap between lines
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          height: 30,
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: Text(
            'hallo',
            style: TextStyle(background: _paint,),
          ),
        ),
        ...
```

This is how it should look like - but the red text should be vertically centered:

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wrap your `Container` inside a `Column` and set the `mainAxisAlignment` to Center

```
  new Container(
                  height: 30,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'hallo',
                        style: TextStyle(background: _paint),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Too bad there isn't a less-hacky way of doing this, but it does work.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think we should use `Column` for alignment purposes. A better way is to use Align widget as shown below:

```
Container(
  height: 30,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.grey[200],
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
  ),
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      'hallo',
      style: TextStyle(background: _paint),
    ),
  ),
),
```

If you have only one child widget and need to align vertically. The best option is using align widget shown below.

Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft)

Comment: When trying this approach the Container uses the whole width of the screen, which doesn't happen when using a Column. Do you know a way of preventing this without assigning a hard width?

Comment: Works like a charm, and much better than wrapping stuff inside Column or Row

Comment: This doesn't work for my case, because it takes the whole width of the screen, as @Chamanhm said.

Answer (score 8):

```
           Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1), color: Colors.blueGrey),
                child:Text('Enter a url')

              )
```

Comment: In my case can't with fixed width

Answer (score 2):

To align vertically and horizontally, just use Align widget:

```
   Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      'hallo',
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

if you wrap your Texts inside a row add a property

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

like

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
      Text(ucfirst(activity.name),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 21,),
    ),
```

That should work for you if you have many Text Widgets inside a row or a single one, see my output below.

[image]